# JMenuItem-adding event listener

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

How can I handle adding `JMenuItem` (`newItem`) to the `JMenu` (`menuUsers`)? Is there a proper `ActionListener` for this purpose? There is a part of code that performs adding menu items to menu. It performs when some event is raised. Here it is:

```
public void UpdateUserList(Map<String, UserSchedule> allSchedule) throws Exception {
    menuUsers.removeAll();
    Iterator it = allSchedule.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem(entry.getKey().toString());
        newItem.setName("User");
        menuUsers.add(newItem);
    }
}
```

I'd like to be like this (pseudo-code):

```
menuUsers.addSomeListener(new SomeListener()
{
    void performWhenNewItemAdded(...) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can I handle adding JMenuItem (newItem) to the menu (menuUsers)?"

For `JmenuItems` I would use an `Action` istead. You can add images, text, tooltips, and key bindings to them. Also they can be reused by other components. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583281/2587435) for a couple examples.

Here's a screenshot if what can be accomplished. You don't need any `JMenuItems` or `ActionListener`s at all. Just add the `Action` to the `JMenu`. See more at [**How to use Actions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

[image]

---

To answer the question more directly...

> "Is there a proper ActionListener for this purpes?"

You are doing it wrong. You appear to be trying to add an `ActionListener` to the `JMenu`. Instead the `ActionListener` should be added to the `JMenuItem`. See more at [**How to use Menus**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

```
jMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do  something
    }
});
```

---

If for some reason you *did* want to add a listener to the `JMenu` and *not* the `JMenuItem`, you should use a `MenuListener` that listens foe `MenuEvents`, where the following are the only three methods you can override.  There is no method for when an `JMenuItem` is added.

```
 userMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener(){
     @Override
     public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
         // Invoked when the menu is canceled.
     }

     @Override
     public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
        // Invoked when the menu is deselected.
     }

     @Override
     public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e)
        // Invoked when a menu is selected.
     }
 });
```

---

Comment: You probably didn't understand me. I meant that I need handler for event, that raised when menuitems are being added to the menu. Sorry for my english

Comment: Read the very last line of the answer, before the code block

Comment: But MenuEvent doesn't raised when following statement is performed: menuUser.add(newItem). MenuEvent is raised when user is doing smth with the menu in window. I have to catch adding new item to my menu.