# JButton with actionPerformed and keyReleased

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton, I want it to do something when the button is pressed and I want it to do the same thing when a key is pressed, how do I do that?

Comment: please whats -- `when a key is pressed,` -- because only `ENTER` and `TAB` keys are built_in accelerators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something when a button is pressed you should add an `ActionListener` to that button like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

And to response to key pressed do something like this : (for example if user enters control alt 7)

```
Action actionListener = new AbstractAction() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    JButton source = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
    System.out.println("Activated: " + source.getText());// just for test
  }
};
//.....

KeyStroke controlAlt7 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control alt 7");
InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap();
inputMap.put(controlAlt7, ACTION_KEY);
ActionMap actionMap = button.getActionMap();
actionMap.put(ACTION_KEY, actionListener);
```

Comment: +1, for the Key Bindings, but the code should use an `Action`, not an ActionListener. Then the Action can be used by the button and the key bindings.

Comment: May I have a full example?

Comment: @KiraHelsing- Hope [this](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html) helps.

Comment: @camickr- I'm glad that you found my answer useful, and sorry if the second part of my answer is a little confusing; indeed action listener is an `Action`, and its name is just for being meaningful. Anyway I edit my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (haven't messed with Swing in a couple of years...) the only key button events that can act upon a button are `Tab` which changes the element focus, `Enter` which fires the `actionPerformed` method and mnemonics, which also fire the `actionPerformed`.

To handle events on button clicks, you could do something like so:

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the `Action` API. You can see more at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). You can use the `Action` for buttons (works like an `ActionListener`) and you can add key shortcuts to it.

You can see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583281/2587435) where key shortcuts are added to the toolbar button as well as the menu items. The interesting thing you mat want to notice is the the menu item and the tool bar button share the same `Action` and thus do the same thing.

[image]

Comment: +1, for using an `Action` and not an ActionListener. Now the Action can be used by the button and by the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            //do your work here
            System.out.println("You clicked the submit button");
        }
    });
```

This is how to use actionlistener with jbutton

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EventedButtonExample extends JFrame {
    private JButton simpleButton;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                EventedButtonExample me = new EventedButtonExample();
                me.initialize();
                me.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    void initialize() {
        simpleButton = new JButton("I am an simple, evented button!");
        CompoundEventHandler eh = new CompoundEventHandler();
        simpleButton.addActionListener(eh);
        simpleButton.addKeyListener(eh);
        getContentPane().add(simpleButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    class CompoundEventHandler extends KeyAdapter implements ActionListener {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            System.out.println("Key pressed: " + keyCode + " (" + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode) + ")");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("A button is pressed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener!!! Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`. All Swing components use Key Bindings to handle keyboard events.

Comment: But keybindings requires a dedicated combination, they are not works as well for example debugging purposes. Because I do not know what is the exact plan of the post opener, I usually try replicate exact behavior what he want to do.